# What's the correct way to download webrtc source code?

Tags: linux, webrtc

I'm trying to follow the instructions outlined here:

http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development#TOC-Before-you-start;

but "fetch webrtc" fails with a message that implies a file (src/buildtools/linux32/gn.sha1) is not found.  See this post for more detail on the error message:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/Dt-GRIlLVe4

I've walked through installation of all the "prerequisite software" as described on the above page, but consistently hit the same error.  I'm doing this from a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine, any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here...

It appears that the problem is related to the fact that I am behind a proxy
and the --no_auth option is used (in depot_tools) when the download_from_google_storage.py script is called.
After reading this post: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/241 
I modified my copy of "download_from_google_storage.py" so that the --no_auth option would have no affect.  I also created a ~/.boto file with three lines:

```
[Boto]
proxy = my.proxy.goes.here.com
proxy_port = PROXY_PORT_NUMBER
```

Then I re-ran "fetch webrtc" and it completed successfully in about 75 minutes.
Go figure...

Answer (score 1):

gn is a replacement for gyp to generate Ninja files.  I don't *think* it's required yet (gn is a work-in-progress), but that's likely what you're missing.  You could comment out gn from the DEPS and see if things work.

Comment: What DEPS are you referring to?  Based on the steps here: http://www.webrtc.org/native-code/development, I don't have a DEPS file till after "fetch webrtc" fails; but then "fetch webrtc" is supposedly not restartable.  Is that page the proper procedure for getting the source code?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar enough with google's client tools to answer that.  I normally grab webrtc directly and use gclient sync

Comment: I'd prefer to do it that way myself; however I thought I'd be "good" and just follow the published procedure.  :-(  When you grab it directly do you use this: "git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc"  ?